# Creating a frequency table for a text file with alphabets?

Tags: arrays, c

I'm looking to creating a C array frequency table for a text file with repeated alphabets. So for example if I had a small file named "text.txt" with the contents: "AAAABBBB\nCCCCEE" and I wanted to parse this file into a byte unsigned int array of 256 bytes, where the index into this array would be the integer value of the source alphabet symbol, how would I go about doing it? I'm not sure how to represent the alphabet in the array as well as its frequency in the same array.

Comment: Is this a homework question? I am asking because there are [community guidelines on answering homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/12149471), and I need to know whether they apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm not sure how to represent the alphabet in the array as well as its frequency in the same array.

You don't have to represent the alphabet in the array. You only have to represent the frequency counters themselves. This is because the alphabet itself is implied by the position of the frequency counters in the array. For example, if you define the array like this

```
unsigned char counters[256] = {0};
```

then you could make `counters['A']` represent the frequency of the upper-case letter `'A`', and `counters['Z']` represent the frequency of the upper-case letter `'Z'`. Assuming that you are using [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), then `counters['A']` is equivalent to writing `counters[65]` and `counters['Z']` is equivalent to writing `counters[90]`.

You could then just go through the input file character by character by calling [`fgetc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) in a loop, and for every character that you encounter, you increment the corresponding counter.

Note that if you only assign an `unsigned char` (a single byte) to each counter, then the counter can only represent numbers up to 256. Therefore, you may want to consider using an `unsigned int` instead.

In accordance with the [community guidelines on homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/12149471), I will not provide a full code solution at this time. However, I can add such a solution later, if necessary.

Comment: Ahhh got it, thank you so much for clearing that up! This was actually related to a homework assignment, yes, but I don't think I'll require the code, I was only struggling with the question itself and the fundamental aspect of it, which is now cleared.